# Catch the event of a blocked instance only after a timeout

Tags: bpmn, flowable

I have a program where I start several process instances using a cron. For each process instance I have a maximum time, and if the execution time exceeds it, I have to consider it as failure and use some specific methods.
For now what I did was simply to check, once my process instance has finished, if the elapsed time exceeds or not the given maximum time.
But what if my process instance gets blocked for some reason (e.g. server not responding)? I need to catch this event and perform failure operations as soon as the process gets blocked and timeout is exceeded.
How can I catch these two conditions?
I had a look at the `FlowableEngineEventType`, but there isn’t a `PROCESS_BLOCKED/SUSPENDED` type of event. But, even if it were, how do I fire it only if a certain amount of time has passed?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is the same question as [this](https://forum.flowable.org/t/catch-the-event-of-a-blocked-instance-only-after-a-timeout/3831) from the Flowable Forum.

If you are using the Flowable [HTTP Task](https://www.flowable.org/docs/userguide/index.html#bpmnHttpTask) then have a look at the documentation to see how you can set the timeouts on it and how you can react on errors there. If you are firing GET requests from your own code you would need to write your own business logic that would throw some kind of BpmnError and you would then handle that in your process.

The Flowable Process instance does not have the concept of being blocked, and you have to manually to that in your modelling.